# While building Project, error in :app:compileDebugJava. It says error: package android.support.v7.app does not exist

Tags: android, android-studio

I have all the required dependencies in the Module Settings. I have also installed all the support libraries using the sdk manager.

I get the following output from the Gradle Console

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild
:app:compileDebugNdk
:app:preDebugBuild
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72103Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42103Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices6587Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJava
/Users/AMTAGRWL/Downloads/Dropbox/GT:CLASSES/Spring 2015/CS 2340/git/TrueProjectUnicorn/ShoppingWithFriends/app/src/main/java/com/projectunicorn/shoppingwithfriends/LoginConfim.java:4: error: package android.support.v7.app does not exist
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
                             ^
/Users/AMTAGRWL/Downloads/Dropbox/GT:CLASSES/Spring 2015/CS 2340/git/TrueProjectUnicorn/ShoppingWithFriends/app/src/main/java/com/projectunicorn/shoppingwithfriends/LoginConfim.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
public class LoginConfim extends ActionBarActivity {
                                 ^
  symbol: class ActionBarActivity
/Users/AMTAGRWL/Downloads/Dropbox/GT:CLASSES/Spring 2015/CS 2340/git/TrueProjectUnicorn/ShoppingWithFriends/app/src/main/java/com/projectunicorn/shoppingwithfriends/RegistrationScreen.java:4: error: package android.support.v7.app does not exist
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
                             ^
/Users/AMTAGRWL/Downloads/Dropbox/GT:CLASSES/Spring 2015/CS 2340/git/TrueProjectUnicorn/ShoppingWithFriends/app/src/main/java/com/projectunicorn/shoppingwithfriends/RegistrationScreen.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
public class RegistrationScreen extends ActionBarActivity {
                                        ^
  symbol: class ActionBarActivity
/Users/AMTAGRWL/Downloads/Dropbox/GT:CLASSES/Spring 2015/CS 2340/git/TrueProjectUnicorn/ShoppingWithFriends/app/src/main/java/com/projectunicorn/shoppingwithfriends/WelcomeScreen.java:4: error: package android.support.v7.app does not exist
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
                             ^
/Users/AMTAGRWL/Downloads/Dropbox/GT:CLASSES/Spring 2015/CS 2340/git/TrueProjectUnicorn/ShoppingWithFriends/app/src/main/java/com/projectunicorn/shoppingwithfriends/WelcomeScreen.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
public class WelcomeScreen extends ActionBarActivity {
                                   ^
  symbol: class ActionBarActivity
/Users/AMTAGRWL/Downloads/Dropbox/GT:CLASSES/Spring 2015/CS 2340/git/TrueProjectUnicorn/ShoppingWithFriends/app/src/main/java/com/projectunicorn/shoppingwithfriends/LoginConfim.java:13: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
/Users/AMTAGRWL/Downloads/Dropbox/GT:CLASSES/Spring 2015/CS 2340/git/TrueProjectUnicorn/ShoppingWithFriends/app/src/main/java/com/projectunicorn/shoppingwithfriends/LoginConfim.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ^
  symbol:   variable super
  location: class LoginConfim
/Users/AMTAGRWL/Downloads/Dropbox/GT:CLASSES/Spring 2015/CS 2340/git/TrueProjectUnicorn/ShoppingWithFriends/app/src/main/java/com/projectunicorn/shoppingwithfriends/LoginConfim.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_confim);
        ^
  symbol:   method setContentView(int)
  location: class LoginConfim
/Users/AMTAGRWL/Downloads/Dropbox/GT:CLASSES/Spring 2015/CS 2340/git/TrueProjectUnicorn/ShoppingWithFriends/app/src/main/java/com/projectunicorn/shoppingwithfriends/LoginConfim.java:20: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
/Users/AMTAGRWL/Downloads/Dropbox/GT:CLASSES/Spring 2015/CS 2340/git/TrueProjectUnicorn/ShoppingWithFriends/app/src/main/java/com/projectunicorn/shoppingwithfriends/LoginConfim.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_login_confim, menu);
        ^
  symbol:   method getMenuInflater()
  location: class LoginConfim
/Users/AMTAGRWL/Downloads/Dropbox/GT:CLASSES/Spring 2015/CS 2340/git/TrueProjectUnicorn/ShoppingWithFriends/app/src/main/java/com/projectunicorn/shoppingwithfriends/LoginConfim.java:27: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
/Users/AMTAGRWL/Downloads/Dropbox/GT:CLASSES/Spring 2015/CS 2340/git/TrueProjectUnicorn/ShoppingWithFriends/app/src/main/java/com/projectunicorn/shoppingwithfriends/LoginConfim.java:39: error: cannot find symbol
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
               ^
  symbol:   variable super
  location: class LoginConfim
/Users/AMTAGRWL/Downloads/Dropbox/GT:CLASSES/Spring 2015/CS 2340/git/TrueProjectUnicorn/ShoppingWithFriends/app/src/main/java/com/projectunicorn/shoppingwithfriends/LoginConfim.java:43: error: cannot find symbol
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WelcomeScreen.class));
                                 ^
  symbol:   method getApplicationContext()
  location: class LoginConfim
/Users/AMTAGRWL/Downloads/Dropbox/GT:CLASSES/Spring 2015/CS 2340/git/TrueProjectUnicorn/ShoppingWithFriends/app/src/main/java/com/projectunicorn/shoppingwithfriends/LoginConfim.java:43: error: cannot find symbol
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WelcomeScreen.class));
        ^
  symbol:   method startActivity(Intent)
  location: class LoginConfim
/Users/AMTAGRWL/Downloads/Dropbox/GT:CLASSES/Spring 2015/CS 2340/git/TrueProjectUnicorn/ShoppingWithFriends/app/src/main/java/com/projectunicorn/shoppingwithfriends/RegistrationScreen.java:13: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
/Users/AMTAGRWL/Downloads/Dropbox/GT:CLASSES/Spring 2015/CS 2340/git/TrueProjectUnicorn/ShoppingWithFriends/app/src/main/java/com/projectunicorn/shoppingwithfriends/RegistrationScreen.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ^
  symbol:   variable super
  location: class RegistrationScreen
/Users/AMTAGRWL/Downloads/Dropbox/GT:CLASSES/Spring 2015/CS 2340/git/TrueProjectUnicorn/ShoppingWithFriends/app/src/main/java/com/projectunicorn/shoppingwithfriends/RegistrationScreen.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration_screen);
        ^
  symbol:   method setContentView(int)
  location: class RegistrationScreen
/Users/AMTAGRWL/Downloads/Dropbox/GT:CLASSES/Spring 2015/CS 2340/git/TrueProjectUnicorn/ShoppingWithFriends/app/src/main/java/com/projectunicorn/shoppingwithfriends/RegistrationScreen.java:20: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
/Users/AMTAGRWL/Downloads/Dropbox/GT:CLASSES/Spring 2015/CS 2340/git/TrueProjectUnicorn/ShoppingWithFriends/app/src/main/java/com/projectunicorn/shoppingwithfriends/RegistrationScreen.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_registration_screen, menu);
        ^
  symbol:   method getMenuInflater()
  location: class RegistrationScreen
/Users/AMTAGRWL/Downloads/Dropbox/GT:CLASSES/Spring 2015/CS 2340/git/TrueProjectUnicorn/ShoppingWithFriends/app/src/main/java/com/projectunicorn/shoppingwithfriends/RegistrationScreen.java:27: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
/Users/AMTAGRWL/Downloads/Dropbox/GT:CLASSES/Spring 2015/CS 2340/git/TrueProjectUnicorn/ShoppingWithFriends/app/src/main/java/com/projectunicorn/shoppingwithfriends/RegistrationScreen.java:39: error: cannot find symbol
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
               ^
  symbol:   variable super
  location: class RegistrationScreen
/Users/AMTAGRWL/Downloads/Dropbox/GT:CLASSES/Spring 2015/CS 2340/git/TrueProjectUnicorn/ShoppingWithFriends/app/src/main/java/com/projectunicorn/shoppingwithfriends/RegistrationScreen.java:42: error: cannot find symbol
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WelcomeScreen.class));
                                 ^
  symbol:   method getApplicationContext()
  location: class RegistrationScreen
/Users/AMTAGRWL/Downloads/Dropbox/GT:CLASSES/Spring 2015/CS 2340/git/TrueProjectUnicorn/ShoppingWithFriends/app/src/main/java/com/projectunicorn/shoppingwithfriends/RegistrationScreen.java:42: error: cannot find symbol
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WelcomeScreen.class));
        ^
  symbol:   method startActivity(Intent)
  location: class RegistrationScreen
/Users/AMTAGRWL/Downloads/Dropbox/GT:CLASSES/Spring 2015/CS 2340/git/TrueProjectUnicorn/ShoppingWithFriends/app/src/main/java/com/projectunicorn/shoppingwithfriends/WelcomeScreen.java:13: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
/Users/AMTAGRWL/Downloads/Dropbox/GT:CLASSES/Spring 2015/CS 2340/git/TrueProjectUnicorn/ShoppingWithFriends/app/src/main/java/com/projectunicorn/shoppingwithfriends/WelcomeScreen.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ^
  symbol:   variable super
  location: class WelcomeScreen
/Users/AMTAGRWL/Downloads/Dropbox/GT:CLASSES/Spring 2015/CS 2340/git/TrueProjectUnicorn/ShoppingWithFriends/app/src/main/java/com/projectunicorn/shoppingwithfriends/WelcomeScreen.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome_screen);
        ^
  symbol:   method setContentView(int)
  location: class WelcomeScreen
/Users/AMTAGRWL/Downloads/Dropbox/GT:CLASSES/Spring 2015/CS 2340/git/TrueProjectUnicorn/ShoppingWithFriends/app/src/main/java/com/projectunicorn/shoppingwithfriends/WelcomeScreen.java:20: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
/Users/AMTAGRWL/Downloads/Dropbox/GT:CLASSES/Spring 2015/CS 2340/git/TrueProjectUnicorn/ShoppingWithFriends/app/src/main/java/com/projectunicorn/shoppingwithfriends/WelcomeScreen.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_welcome_screen, menu);
        ^
  symbol:   method getMenuInflater()
  location: class WelcomeScreen
/Users/AMTAGRWL/Downloads/Dropbox/GT:CLASSES/Spring 2015/CS 2340/git/TrueProjectUnicorn/ShoppingWithFriends/app/src/main/java/com/projectunicorn/shoppingwithfriends/WelcomeScreen.java:27: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
/Users/AMTAGRWL/Downloads/Dropbox/GT:CLASSES/Spring 2015/CS 2340/git/TrueProjectUnicorn/ShoppingWithFriends/app/src/main/java/com/projectunicorn/shoppingwithfriends/WelcomeScreen.java:39: error: cannot find symbol
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
               ^
  symbol:   variable super
  location: class WelcomeScreen
/Users/AMTAGRWL/Downloads/Dropbox/GT:CLASSES/Spring 2015/CS 2340/git/TrueProjectUnicorn/ShoppingWithFriends/app/src/main/java/com/projectunicorn/shoppingwithfriends/WelcomeScreen.java:43: error: cannot find symbol
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ShoppingWithFriendsLogin.class));
                                 ^
  symbol:   method getApplicationContext()
  location: class WelcomeScreen
/Users/AMTAGRWL/Downloads/Dropbox/GT:CLASSES/Spring 2015/CS 2340/git/TrueProjectUnicorn/ShoppingWithFriends/app/src/main/java/com/projectunicorn/shoppingwithfriends/WelcomeScreen.java:43: error: cannot find symbol
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ShoppingWithFriendsLogin.class));
        ^
  symbol:   method startActivity(Intent)
  location: class WelcomeScreen
/Users/AMTAGRWL/Downloads/Dropbox/GT:CLASSES/Spring 2015/CS 2340/git/TrueProjectUnicorn/ShoppingWithFriends/app/src/main/java/com/projectunicorn/shoppingwithfriends/WelcomeScreen.java:47: error: cannot find symbol
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegistrationScreen.class));
                                 ^
  symbol:   method getApplicationContext()
  location: class WelcomeScreen
/Users/AMTAGRWL/Downloads/Dropbox/GT:CLASSES/Spring 2015/CS 2340/git/TrueProjectUnicorn/ShoppingWithFriends/app/src/main/java/com/projectunicorn/shoppingwithfriends/WelcomeScreen.java:47: error: cannot find symbol
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegistrationScreen.class));
        ^
  symbol:   method startActivity(Intent)
  location: class WelcomeScreen
/Users/AMTAGRWL/Downloads/Dropbox/GT:CLASSES/Spring 2015/CS 2340/git/TrueProjectUnicorn/ShoppingWithFriends/app/src/main/java/com/projectunicorn/shoppingwithfriends/WelcomeScreen.java:50: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
36 errors

 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2.692 secs
```

I have tried multiple existing posts regarding this but have failed to find a solution that works.

EDIT: My build.gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.projectunicorn.shoppingwithfriends"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),                        'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
    compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3')
    compile ('com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.+')
}
```

I'm using Android Studio 1.0.2 on OS X Yosemite.

Answer (score 0):

Installing the library is not enough. You also need to add it to the list of dependencies of your project.

To do that, add this line to the dependencies section of your build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
  ...
  compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3')
  compile ('com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3')
}
```

This was taken from the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7):

> **v7 appcompat library**
>
> Note: This library depends on the v4 Support Library. If you are using Ant or Eclipse, make sure you include the v4 Support Library as part of this library's classpath.

So don't forgot to add both v4 and v7.

Comment: You want `support` v4 and `appcompat` v7.

Answer (score 0):

What versions do you choose when create project? (target, minimum, etc)

I change all to one version - API 21, it works for me.

Comment: Update the question to show the build.grade file. Do you think this is correct? I think I have all of them at the same version.

Comment: I use Eclipse, windows. When i have same problem - i change all version(minimum, target and compile with) to one version and it is compile ok.